# How to calculate mean values of all cells of raster files in R?

Tags: raster, r, terra, average, mean

I have monthly raster (.tiff) files such as 200501.tif, 200502.tif and so on...till 202012.tif.

I want to calculate mean values of each raster (i.e. of all the cells (all rows and columns) of each raster file) (cellStats(r, 'mean')) and export them in a .csv or .xls as two columns:

```
Date     Value
Jan 2005  25
Feb 2005  36
...
...
...
Dec 2020  12
```

I am doing it in R.

Comment: It helps to break a question down into small units. Do you know how to compute the mean of a single raster file? Do you know how to loop over a set of files? Do you know how to write a CSV file? You can find out how to do most of these things online, and keeping questions here *focussed* means its easier for people to build solutions for more complex problems like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `global` function from `{terra}` library:

```
library(terra)

r = rast()

values(r) = 1:ncell(r)

global(r, 'mean')
#          mean
# lyr.1 32400.5
```

---

For a reproducible example I'm adding a list of random rasters loaded into a list:

```
library(terra)

set.seed(123)

r = rast()
rl <- sapply(1:48, function(X) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r))))
```

For computing mean for every element of the raster list, use `lapply` with `global` function:

```
means = lapply(rl, function(x) global(x, 'mean'))

means = do.call(rbind.data.frame, means)
row.names(means) = paste0(rep(2005:2008,each=12),sprintf("%02d",rep(1:12,times=4)))

head(means)
#                 mean
# 200501  0.0001132137
# 200502  0.0046515731
# 200503  0.0041824118
# 200504  0.0010558954
# 200505 -0.0035873522
# 200506  0.0027042357
```

For saving the result to your machine, use `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(means, 'path/to/means.csv')
```

---

Adaptation to OP code:

```
library(terra)

f = list.files(path="D:/Test/", pattern=".tiff$", full.names=TRUE)
rl = lapply(f, function(x) rast(x))

means = lapply(rl, function(x) global(x, 'mean'))
means = do.call(rbind.data.frame, means)

write.csv(means, 'path/to/means.csv')
```

Comment: That's a start - for a complete answer the code would have to loop over the files, and maybe build a data frame of dates from the file name and values from the raster, to be written out using `write.csv` at the end, or write each line inside the loop using `cat`...

Comment: You're right. I edited the answer. Thank you

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thanks for your response. I have three doubts. It would be helpful if you can please clarify. I defined f <- list.files(path="D:/Test/", pattern=".tiff$", full.names=TRUE)
r <- rast(f) Is that correct? And what is X in function (X) while defining r1? because it is giving me the warning: [setValues] values were recycled. And could you please explain what is happening in sprintf("%02d",rep(1:12,times=4)

Comment: 1) I just added the adaption of your code in my answer. 2) it's a dummy argument for creating dummy rasters with random numbers. 3) `sprintf("%02d",rep(1:12,times=4)` is for adding leading zeros, that's for the reproducible example only, your names should be different than mines